# How to draw integral curves?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, numerical-methods

I'm trying to better understand vector fields and integral curves. I'm coming from computer programming background.

My vector field is defined such that at any point on plane $p(x, y)$ I can calculate corresponding vector $v(x, y)$.

This may sound very basic, but I can't find answer anywhere. Given this setup, how can I actually draw an [integral curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve) starting at any given point?

I tried to create a simple vector field $F(x,y) = [-y, x]$. If I sample this vector field over `2d` mesh, and render normalized vector at each sampled point, I get something like this:

[image]

Now I want to render integral curves for this field, but I don't understand how. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't necessary has access to analytical form of vector field (we can sample it, but we don't know its function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This capability is implemented in many programs, including [matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/streamline.html), [mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html), and [matplotlib](https://scipython.com/blog/visualizing-a-vector-field-with-matplotlib/).

If you want to know the underlying algorithms, they work by [numerically solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations#Methods) 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}(t))$$
where $\mathbf{v}$ is your vector field.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this algorithm. Could you please expand your answer? The wikipedia article shows a very simple example with one variable. How can I generalize it to two-dimensional case?

Comment: Doh, turns out Runge-Kutta method worked all this time. I just had this field defined as $F(x,y) = [-y/x, 1]$, which created problems when `x == 0`. Need to figure out how to solve them, but your answer is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plot to approximate the curve. Start at the initial condition $p(x_0,y_0)$ and then move along the vector field. 
Next point would be $ p(x_0,y_0)+tv(x_0,y_0)$ for some small $t$
Then repeat this process, connect the points by a straight line and this way you can draw aproximations to the integral curves.

Comment: I tried that - looks like the curve diverges: https://i.imgur.com/W5LgJwi.png . If I plot this vector field in wolfram alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vector+field+(-y,+x) - it gives nice circles: https://i.imgur.com/rYGRiDw.png

Comment: @Anvaka yep that's why I said approximation. Reduce the value of $t$, the curve would be the limit as $T$ goes to 0.

Comment: Or you can use Runge Kutta for higher order appx

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you can select a starting point from the grid, then use the higher-order methods such as RK4 method to calculate the next value, since your function is a circle and the derivatives contain zero and infinity.
Then to fix the issue of numerical error, you might want to compare the your next value with the values on the grid, and then choose a point on the grid as the next point, then repeat the process.
And if you wish, you can smooth your points by some spline methods.